# Wordpress + RSS Multi Import: Autotag post content?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, import, rss

I use the Wordpress plugin "RSS Multi import". This plugin automatically imports the first two sentences from each post into the database. No interference from user, just fully automated posting.

Is there a way to make each word of the content also available to that post as a seperate tag? For example, a post with content "The quick fox jumps over the fence" would have seven tags ("the", "quick", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the" and "fence"). I will run a custom script (trough cronjob) to remove unwanted keywords.

Does anyone know of a way to edit RSS Multi Importer so that it also creates tags while autoposting? Or any other plugin/PHP script that achieves the same?

Comment: In addition: The plugin seems to be abandoned by its author. If anyone knows a free alternative to RSS-Multi-Import (with feed-to-post and categories), feel free to contribute! :)